# StartActivityForResult() starts other app but instantly returns RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

When I try to `startForResult` another app via `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` using the new `androidx.activity.result` API, this other app is started but in my calling app I immediately get the `RESULT_CANCELED`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val startForResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message)?.text = "RETURNED OK!! "
            }
            else if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message)?.text = "RETURNED CANCELED!!"
            }
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        val button = findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            startForResult.launch(getMyapplicationIntent())
        }
    }

    private fun getMyapplicationIntent(): Intent? {
        return packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.myapplication")
    }
}
```

with *queries* in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.myapplication" />
</queries>
```

Comment: Since the launch `Intent` does not return a result, you can get rid of most of that code and just call `startActivity()` on the `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Launch Intent cannot return a result? That is a good information! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that happen when the intent used to launch the activity have the flag

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Davide's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75336205/) notice is correct!

Official Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) states about `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` that:

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.

...which is **EXACTLY** what we are expecting from `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()`

My solution for the permission `Activities` is following (*in AndroidManifest.xml*)

```
<!-- Some permission Activity -->
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    ...
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    ... />
```